# Is the function uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Let function $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a bounded and differentiable function. If both the function and its derivative are square integrable, is the function uniformly continuous?

Note that the derivative of $f$ is not assumed bounded.

Comment: Yes, $f$ is Holder with exponent $1/2$. First, prove that $f$ is an indefinite integral of $f'$ (using the mean value theorem). Then apply Holder's inequality.

Comment: Thank you for your  answer. I suppose that the boundedness assumption on $f$ is also redundant?

Comment: Yes, I think it's not needed. Neither is integrability of $f$.